# Harvard Multiple authors- Alphabetical or not?

Tags: research-process, writing, citations, thesis

I apologise if I have missed this in the Harvard guidelines but I was wondering whether the order of multiple authors matters. For example a book by A Smith and A Jones. How should it be written:

(Smith & Jones, 2014)
 Smith, A. and Jones, A. 2010. Another Book. 5th ed. New York [etc.]: Book Pub.

or must it be written alphabetical of surname:

(Jones & Smith, 2014) 
Jones, A. and Smith, A. 2010. Another Book. 5th ed. New York [etc.]: Book Pub.

I understand all the other rules regarding the list been alphabetical and date ordered where multiple authors exist but haven’t seen anything explicitly mentioning this.

Thank You

Comment: There is no way any referencing standard would allow the author list to be changed.

Comment: When you say you have looked at the "Harvard guidelines" what do you mean? I would suggest you look at the APA or MLA style handbooks (both variants of Harvard referencing), they should answer your question.

Comment: @StrongBad the OP has already stated they were not able to find it in the guidelines

Comment: @Magpie and I was asking for clarification on which guidelines the OP looked at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use the order of authors as given in the book or article, regardless of the reference style (Harvard or otherwise).

The order of authors has some significance in many disciplines (for example, in my field the first author is the one who did the most work). So, no referencing system asks you to change the order of authors.